# RestKit requests not being sent properly

Tags: ios, restkit

I am using restkit 0.10.0 for a project. In some rare cases, it seems that the app gets into a state where all http requests sent via restkit simply does not get handled, i.e., they are never processed. I've been through the bugs on github but cannot find a bug matching.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? I've looked at [5th consecutive RestKit call not being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894267/5th-consecutive-restkit-call-not-being-sent) but cannot reproduce this problem.

EDIT: 
This might not be RestKit's fault after all. I have the TestFlight SDK 1.0 integrated, and people in [Why does NSURLConnection fail to reach the backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149811/why-does-nsurlconnection-fail-to-reach-the-backend) suggests that it may cause NSURLConnection to not call success/error callbacks

Comment: For more Output and Logging use this code, when RestKit is initialized.

     RKLogInitialize();
    RKLogConfigureFromEnvironment();
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

Comment: Thanks. I'm already logging. The problem is that it's very hard to reproduce the bug since I'm not sure what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using RestKit 0.10.1 in my app wich downloads certain image tiles to view an image in different resolution levels. So RestKit handles lots of traffic for me but I have never had the problem you're mentioning. Could you provide more info or some console output? You can always try and use newer or older versions of RestKit and see if the problem still occurs.

[RestKit v0.9.3](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/RestKit-0.9.3)

[Restkit v0.10.1](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Restkit-0.10.1)

Comment: I've upgraded to 0.10.1, but see no improvements wrt. the problem. However, I may not be RestKit causing my problems. See my edit